# Handling dynamically added double quotes with ajax and jquery

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

The below code sends the value of two input fields to another service via API. It works fine until one of the input values contains a double quote `"`, in which case the API will return error 400 (bad request) when submitting.

```
var summary = $("#summary").val();
var title = $("#title").val();
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl + apiKey + '&summary=' + summary + '&title=' + title,
    type: 'POST',
    data: (function(title, summary) {
        return ['{ "summary" : "',summary,'" , "title" : "',title,'" }'].join("");
    })(title,summary),
    beforeSend: function () { },
    success: function () { },
    error: function (error) { }
});
```

The code will also work fine when using single quotes `'`.

An example of the text that should be able to go through: `"This is a quote from Someone Smart." ~ Someone Smart`

I tried escaping both values, tried the encodeURIComponent, both suggested by some fellow stackoverflowers on other similiar questions, but somehow failed to make it work.

Comment: First, it looks like you're sending the data in both url parameters and the body, which shouldn't be necessary. Second, don't try to build json strings by concatenating, create a js object and call `JSON.stringify()` on it. Also, in some cases, you can simply assign the js object to the `data` property.

Comment: @JasonP thanks, I'll try out this thing with the object and JSON.stringify later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
data: (function(title, summary) {
    return ['{ "summary" : "',summary,'" , "title" : "',title,'" }'].join("");
})(title,summary)
```

Will produce broken JSON if summary or title contains `"` because the quotes won't match then. Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Assuming you have a good reason for creating the closure, the code should look like:

```
data: (function (title, summary) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        summary: summary,
        title: title
    });
})(title, summary),
```